# Reactive Banana: Alternate buttons events

Tags: haskell, wxwidgets, frp, reactive-banana

I am trying for the first time to use Reactive Banana (WX) to display a text like "Pressed button One", "Pressed button Two", etc. on top of five buttons:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Graphics.UI.WX hiding (Event)
import Reactive.Banana
import Reactive.Banana.WX

data Buttons = One | Two | Three | Four | Five deriving (Show)

main :: IO ()
main = start $ do
  f      <- frame [text := “Five Buttons“]
  bone   <- button f [text := “One”]
  btwo   <- button f [text := “Two”]
  bthree <- button f [text := “Three”]
  bfour  <- button f [text := “Four”]
  bfive  <- button f [text := “Five”]
  out    <- staticText f []

  set f [layout := margin 10 $
          column 5 [row 5 [widget bone, widget btwo, widget bthree, widget bfour, widget bfive],
                    grid 5 5 [[label “Output:” , widget out]
                              ]]]

  let networkDescription :: forall t. Frameworks t => Moment t ()
      networkDescription = do
        eone   <- event0 bone   command
        etwo   <- event0 btwo   command
        ethree <- event0 bthree command
        efour  <- event0 bfour  command
        efive  <- event0 bfive  command

        let
          somethinghere::Behaviour t Buttons
          somethinghere = ....
        sink out [text :== "Pressed button " ++ show <$> somethinghere]

  network <- compile networkDescription    
  actuate network
```

The code is just the main skeleton. What I am not able to do at the moment is filling up the `somethinghere` method. As said, if for example the button "One" is pressed, then `somethinghere` should return referring to `Buttons` ADT data `One` and so on.
I tried with [`accumB`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/reactive-banana-0.8.1.2/docs/Reactive-Banana-Combinators.html#v:accumB) and [`unionWith`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/reactive-banana-0.8.1.2/docs/Reactive-Banana-Combinators.html#v:unionWith) but I don't think I am getting right the mechanism. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you want something like:

```
let eChangeSelection :: Event t Buttons
    eChangeSelection = unions
        [ One <$ eone
        , Two <$ etwo
        , Three <$ ethree
        , Four <$ efour
        , Five <$ efive
        ]

    -- Your `somethinghere`:
    bSelection :: Behavior t Buttons
    bSelection = stepper One eChangeSelection
```

`bSelection` represents the currently selected button, and `eChangeSelection` is the stream of updates to it. `unions` merges the five event streams, and `(<$)` tags each individual stream with the appropriate value. Note that I arbitrarily picked `One` as the initial selection value; you might prefer doing something different (e.g. using a `Behavior t (Maybe Buttons)` so that  it is possible to not have a button selected).